# Total days in overlapping date range in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: excel, date-range

A google spreadsheet example of what I am trying to achieve can be found here:  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16x_2NFSyYreBsC0hFA3UuhCGmhZc8fvqtNpVwZn9SRw/edit?usp=sharing

In the above example, I am trying to find out the total number of days from ALL "Normal Ranges" that fall within the "Master Range" start/end.

Note: Please leave "Excel" tag as this is an excel question. I just made the google spreadsheet so that I could share easily with others.

Answer (score 0):

The following formula will give you the number of days for each Normal Range, if it falls within the Master Range:

```
=IF(AND(A2>=$D$2, B2<=$E$2), B2-A2, 0)
```

Then, you can add up the days, using the SUM function.

Comment: Did you paste the above formula in D1? Then, copy and paste it into D2, D3, etc.? What output do you get?